# Задача о сложении строк (окончания английских слов)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание, выполнил его частично и застрял. Часть тестов проходит в системе проверки, но на некоторых обваливается. Сказали, что необходимо обратить внимание на пограничные условия. Какие условия я пропускаю и не рассматриваю в решении?

**Условие:**

> Напишите функцию verbing(s), принимающую на вход строку.
>
> Если длина строки 3 и больше, то добавьте к ней 'ing' в конце.
> Если строка уже содержит 'ing', добавьте 'ly'.
> Если длина строки меньше 3, верните строку как есть.

```
Sample 
Input 1:hail  
Sample Output 1: hailing

Sample Input 2: swiming  
Sample Output 2: swimingly

Sample Input 3: do  
Sample Output 3: do
```

Код:

```
def verbing(s):
    # the len smallest then 3
    if len(s)<3:
        return s
    
    # if ing not in the end. Append ing
    elif len(s)>3 and s[-3:]!="ing":
        return (s+"ing")    
        
    # if ing is in the end. Append ly   
    elif len(s)>3 and s[-3:]=="ing":
        return (s+"ly")
s = "hail"
verbing(s)
```

Comment: @insolori, Спасибо, действительно у меня  по первому условию сравнения  строгое равенство. Оптимальнее перепишу проверку длины

Comment: Исправил и теперь все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def verbing(s):
    # Если длина строки меньше 3, верните строку как есть.
    if len(s) < 3:
        return s

    # Если длина строки 3 и больше, то добавьте к ней 'ing' в конце.
    elif len(s) >= 3:
        return s + "ing"

    # Если строка уже содержит 'ing', добавьте 'ly'.
    elif s.endswith("ing"):
        return s + "ly"
    
    
print(verbing('hail'))     # hailing
print(verbing('swiming'))  # swimingly
print(verbing('do'))       # do
```

**PS.** условие с "содержит" можно и через `in` проверять: `elif "ing" in s:`, но по примерам, думаю `endswith` больше подойдет

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и новый вариант решения. Пока не работал с функцией endswith. Пожалуй стоит обратить на нее внимание.

Comment: @AlexSapsay, если мой ответ подходит, отметьте его

Comment: Если бы я бы препод, то решение с .endswith я бы не принял (т.е. написал бы тест, который бы эту функцию не проходил. Например, строка "Inglourious Basterds"). В тех.задании стоит "содержит", а не "заканчивается" ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик, я о том же подумал, вот и добавил `PS` :)

Comment: А, что-то я до туда не дочитал :)

Comment: последний `elif` никогда не выполнится

Comment: @Danis, действительно, из-за этого во втором случае выведет "swiminging"

Answer (score 3):

Сравнивать длину строки с 3 достаточно одного раза: в самом начале. Если при длине меньше 3 произошел выход из функции, то дальше уже проверка длины не нужна (очевидно, что если выход из функции не произошел, значит длина строки >= 3), нужно просто проверить, что строка оканчивается на `ing`:

```
def verbing(s):
    # the len less then 3
    if len(s) < 3:
        return s
    elif s.endswith('ing'):  # или if s[-3:] == 'ing':
        # if ing is in the end. Append ly
        return s + 'ly'
    else:
        # if ing not in the end. Append ing
        return s + 'ing'


assert verbing('hail') == 'hailing'
assert verbing('swiming') == 'swimingly'
assert verbing('do') == 'do'
assert verbing('fly') == 'flying'
```